# R: why different between [k-means] build-in function and Kmeans from amap package

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I am doing k-means algorithm on iris data using two functions, the regular "kmeans" and "Kmeans" from amap package.

```
irisCluster <- kmeans(iris[, 3:4], 3, nstart = 20,algorithm = "Lloyd");
irisCluster$withinss
#[1] 13.05769 16.29167  2.02200

irisCluster2<-Kmeans(iris[,3:4],3,nstart = 20,method="euclidean");
irisCluster2$withinss
#[1] 0.12010750 0.00113741 0.00596000
```

According to Rhelp, Kmeans when method="euclidean" should return same result as with function kmeans. But clearly from above, they look very different. Why is the case?

Comment: My first inclination is that there is a different default between the two (maybe one is centering the other is not). Second, ¿have you tried different method/algorithm choices to see if others match up?

Comment: Hi. Yes. I did match up the method and algorithm. In kmeans, default is using euclidean distance and I set the algorithm method to be the default one for Kmeans.

Comment: This certainly looks like a software specific question, but given @Anony-Mousse's answer, understanding the [software-specific] reasons for the difference is clearly tied up w/ understanding the methods. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @gung it would be better suited for stackoverflow. Becausr in essence it's just a bug in the package. I wish people would try to look at the sources more.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, to my eye, most of your answer leans on understanding what k-means is & how it should or should not be used. That makes me think it's OK here. If you really want me to migrate it, flag it & I'll send it to [SO].

Answer (score 1):

The amap R package is broken in many ways.

1. K-means does not use Euclidean distance, but *squared* deviations. There is no reason to compute the sqrt.
2. With other distances, such as absolute Pearson correlation, available in amap, k-means may fail to convergeand will *not* find even "locally" optimal solutions. You can't just put other distances into k-means, but you also need to change the *mean*. The means is optimal for squared errors, it is not optimal for other distances. But if you -systematically- never make a good choice for the current cluster center, then the final cluster center will not be good either. For example, PAM ("k-medoids") does something similar for other distances, but fixes the problem of using the mean. Apparently, the amap authors were not aware of this limitation of k-means...
3. Their WSS computation is obviously defect. Instead of the sum of squared deviations, you get the last squared distance only. The comment still contains a different code that didn't have this bug.
4. The default kmeans algorithm (Hartigan Wong) is *much* faster than Lloyds algorithm, and may find better results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I want to use euclidean distance and mahattan distance in kmeans to compare the result, which method do you recommend in r?

Comment: Do not use Manhattan with KMeans. Use k-medians with Manhattan.